# Pass, Receive, and Use function into child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, components

I'm still learning ReactJS / React Native and I'm stuck with a stupid thing I'm sure. Here's my case: I want to receive data in my child component and display it in a Modal. So:

I have a function like this (axios, API, ...):

```
getProductInfo = (product_id) => {
    axios.get(
        `API-EXAMPLE`
    )
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            isVisible: false,
            productInfo: response.data
        })
        console.log(this.state.productInfo);
    })
}
```

I pass the function to my Child Component with the "onModalPress":

```
<CatalogList productsList={this.state.displayProducts} onModalPress={this.getProductInfo}/>
```

And here, some info about the Child Component:

```
const CatalogList = ({productsList, onModalPress}) => (
<Card containerStyle={styles.container}>

<View style={{ padding:20, margin:0, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
{
    productsList.map((p, i) => {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight key={i} onPress={() => onModalPress(p.id)}>
                <View style={style.card}>
                    <View style={style.content}>
                        <View style={{width: 170, zIndex: 2}}>
                            <Text style={style.name}>{p.id}</Text>
                            <Text style={style.name}>{p.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={style.winemaker}>Domaine : {p.domain}</Text>
                            <Text style={style.winemaker}>Origine : {p.wine_origin}</Text>
                            <Text style={style.aop}>Appellation : {p.appellation}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Image
                            style={style.image}
                            source={{ uri: p.image, width: 140, height: 225, }}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={style.entitled}>
                        <Text style={[style.priceText, style.cadetGrey]}>{p.publicPriceText}</Text>
                        <Text style={style.priceText}>{p.subscriberPriceText}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={style.row}>
                        <Text style={[style.price, style.cadetGrey]}>{p.price} €</Text>
                        <Text style={style.price}>{p.subscriber_price} €</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[{backgroundColor: p.label_colour}, style.label]}>
                        <Text style={style.labelText}>{p.label}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Modal isVisible={false}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            {/* <Text>{productInfo.rewiew_wine_waiter}</Text> */}
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    })
}
</View>
  </Card>
);
```

The "p.id" comes from another data (productList) that I get with another Axios API Call. With "p.id" I get the product_id I need in my function

```
getProductInfo
```

Everything works and I display the info inside my console.log (this.state.productInfo).

My issue and I think is easy... It's how can I "store/stock" this info I have in the console.log in a const/props to use it in my Modal and call it like in this example:

```
<Modal isVisible={false}>
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>{productInfo.rewiew_wine_waiter}</Text>
   </View>
</Modal>
```

Of course, any other advice is welcome!

Comment: Where is your console.log?

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: Where do you use this `Modal`? You can pass  `productInfo`, which you are keeping in your state, as a prop to your `Modal`. Can you have a problem with this?

Comment: I updated the code. I put all the code of my Child Component. Here you have the .map where I can get info about every product and I get back the p.id to pass through my function.
The Modal is inside this code
So, when I though a product, I can get the product_id I put in my function but just display it in a console.log

Answer (score 1):

> React is all about one-way data flow down the component hierarchy

Let's assume that you have a `Container` component that fetch all the data:

```
    class MyContainer extends Component{
        state = {
            myItensToDisplay: []
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            //axios request
               .then(res => this.setState({myItensToDisplay: res.itens}))  
        }
    }
```

Looking good! Now you have all the data you want to display fetched and stored in your container's state. Let's pass it to a `Item`component:

```
    class MyContainer extends Component{
        // All the code from above

       render(){
            const itens = this.state.myDataToDisplay.map( item =>{
                return(<Item name={item.name} price={item.price} />);
            })

            return(
                <div>
                    {itens}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Now you are fetching all the data you want to display in a parent component and distributing that data to it's childrens via props.

Comment: Yes I can do that and I'm doing it in the code above. I edited the code of my Child Component. I'm doing a .map through my productList (which I have in my state in my Parent Component). It's where I can get the product_id inside onModalPress(p.id) and display it inside the console.log of the function. 
How can I use it as a prop then ?

Comment: I believe that you are seeing this in the wrong way.You have a `productList` wich means that you have several products fetched in your parent component. Now you have to understand each individual product on this list as a component. So the mapping should occur inside your parent component and return an individual `Product` component for each element on the list. In your parent: `const myProducts = this.state.productlist.map(product => (<Product myprops={product} />))` .
And then just render `{myProducts}` inside your parent